# Populate a table from dropdown in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using asp.net mvc 5. I have created a the following basic application.

I want to add items to a list from a drop down and show them in a html table. For a example i want to add multiple subjects to a student from a drop down and show them in a table under the drop down.
I have created the following view and view model.

```
public class Subject
{
    public string SubjectId {get; set;}
    public string SubjectName {get ; set;}
}

public class StudentViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public List<Subject> subjectlist { get; set; }
}




@model School.Models.StudentViewModel

<form action="" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>Name</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.Name)
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Grade</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.Grade)
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Subject</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Subject, new SelectList(@ViewBag.Subjects, "value", "text"))
        <button>Add</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.subjectlist != null)
            {
                @foreach(var s in subjectlist)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>s.SubjectName</td>
                    </tr>
                }

            }
        </tbody>
    </p>
</form>
```

user should be able to add multiple subjects which selected from drop down when he click the add button.but there is a issue. With my code when i click the add button it successfully add the selected subject to the list add show them in below table.But every time i add the subject it recreate the "subjectlist" and previously added item is not there. what is the problem in my code. someone please help.

here is my controller code.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    StudentViewModel model = new StudentViewModel();
    return View(model);
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(StudentViewModel svm){
    var sub = db.Subjects.Where(x=> x.SubjectId == svm.Subject).FirstOrDefault();
    if(svm.subjectlist == null)
        svm.subjectlist = new List<Subject>();
    svm.subjectlist.Add(sub);
    return View("Index",svm);
 }
```

Comment: You don't generate any controls for the `Subject` so when you post, `if(svm.subjectlist == null)` is always true, so you initialize a new collection and add only the one subject that was selected from the dropdownlist.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is not clear what you said. I have created dropdown controller for Subject and "subjectlist" is the collection that that add the subject that was selected from the dropdownlist. Can you tell me exactly where should I change my code.

Comment: Step through the code in your POST method. Your never post back any existing `Subjects`, just the ID of the new `Subject` you selected in the dropdown. You need to save the `Student` along with the new subject each time then redirect to the edit method, not return the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is great help if you can tell me what is the new code. I am new to asp.net mvc.

Comment: I cant give you the code because I don't even know why you are doing this. Nowhere do you seem to save the `Student` or the associated `Subject`. And why would you not just use a multiple select if you want to assign multiple subjects to a student.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Just tell me in where should i save the student list? I cant save it in a database until the user click a save button. At the last when the user click the save button all the subjects in the subjectlist collection should be inserted to the table. I know how to do that part. But here i have stucked.

Comment: What do you mean _student list_? You view only displays one student. Are you trying to create a new student and select some subjects for that student? If, so create a view model so you can generate a checkbox list displaying all subjects, then post and save everything at once

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry my mistake. It should be subject list. Yes it exactly what i want. Create a new student and add subjects to that student. But i can't use checkboxes. I want to use a dropdown. Please guide me and tell me a way to achieve this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75043/discussion-between-daybreaker-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: What you are wanting to do, without feeding a request back, would be best served in a Client Side MVVM, like Knockout or Angular